# How to get data from multiple tables in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've written a repository like below:

```
@Query("select c.custName,b.ansType from Customer c,Custype b where c.custype_id=b.id")

public List<Customer> findAllByQueryDescription();
```

where custName and ansType properties belong to entity Customer and Custype.

The controller method:

```
        @Autowired CustomerRepository customerRepository; @RequestMapping(value="/customer") 
        public String showCustomer(Model model) { 
           List<Customer> custlist=customerRepository.findAllByQueryDescription(); 
           model.addAttribute("custList",custlist); 
           return "home";
        }
```

Now I want to show data in a data table from both tables using `thymeleaf` for my spring boot mvc project. In my view I've added code like below

```
<tr th:each="${cust:custList}">
  <td th:text="${cust.custName}"></td>
</tr>
```

but errors are being shown at browser like cust.custName not found.

My question is how to get data from multiple tables and display in a table

Comment: I think you need to change the iterator to be `th:each="cust : ${custList}"` in order to populate the local variable `cust` in your iteration loop. How you get the list into `${custList}` is not clear from your question.

Comment: Sorry I've posted wrong code. It is exactly same as you mentioned. But error are being shown.

Comment: Then, on to the next issue - how are you setting the `custList` to the list of customers returned from the repository? It would be useful to update the question with the correct code to avoid confusion also.

Comment: I'm returning as beloow:

Comment: @Autowired
CustomerRepository customerRepository;
@RequestMapping(value="/customer")
public String showCustomer(Model model)
{
  List<Customer> custlist=customerRepository.findAllByQueryDescription();   
  model.addAttribute("custList",custlist);
  return "home";
}

Comment: @miltondatta2012, welcome to StackOverflow. You can edit your question with the details. I updated your question with the details from your comment